# strtok does not work if data are copied from EXCEL

Tags: c, excel, matlab, strtok

I'm using C to call a dll in Matlab. My code reads a file and then prepares the inputs in order to call the dll. Here's the code. When the program reads a .txt file written by me it works properly. However if I paste data from Excel it doesn't work. For example if I paste these data from EXCEL in test.txt file:
" 10.2    20     3     4
  10.4    30     5     6"
and I use the debugger, I saw that the first iteration is correct as inputs_mdl takes the values 10.2, 20, 3 and 4. However in the second it takes "10.4\t30\t\5\t6\t". As a result the code after the second one while is never executed.
What does EXCEL do  to keep strtok from detecting the separator properly?
Thanks!

```
   if ((mdl_initialize && mdl_step && mdl_terminate && mdl_Uptr && mdl_Yptr)) {
    /* === user application initialization function === */
    mdl_initialize(1); 
    /* insert other user defined application initialization code here */

    /* === user application step function === */
    file_acquis=fopen("test.txt","r+");
    file_outputs=fopen("outputs.txt","r+");

    if ((file_acquis==NULL) || (file_outputs==NULL))
    {

        printf ("Check files path");
        return(-1);
    }

    else
    {
        //Checking the file until EOF
        while(fgets(input, 250, file_acquis))
        {
            //Getting token from each line read
            inputs_mdl=strtok(input,separator);
            inputs_model[0]=atof(inputs_mdl);


            //Preparing inputs
            while ((inputs_mdl=strtok(NULL,separator)) !=NULL)
            {       
                inputs_model[k]=atof(inputs_mdl);
                bucle=1;
                k++;
            }
            k=1;
            //Init struct
            if (bucle==1)
            {
                //Init structure
                time_elapsed= inputs_model[0];//
                mdl_Uptr->var1 =inputs_model[1];//
                mdl_Uptr->var2 =inputs_model[2];//
                //Call dll
                mdl_step();

                printf ("retorno matlab");
                printf ("%f\n",mdl_Yptr->output1);
                printf ("%f\n",mdl_Yptr->output2);

                //Getting outputs
                sprintf(string_file_output[0],"%f", mdl_Yptr->output1);
                sprintf(string_file_output[1],"%f", mdl_Yptr->output2);

                //Convert float to string. INPUTS
                for (z=0;z<INPUTS;z++)
                    sprintf(string_file[0],"%f", inputs_model[z]);

                //Concanate
                for (z=1;z<INPUTS;z++)
                {
                    strcat(string_file[0], "    ");
                    strcat(string_file[0], string_file[z]);
                }
                for (z=1;z<OUTPUTS;z++)
                {
                    strcat(string_file[0], "    ");
                    strcat(string_file[0], string_file_output[z]);
                }

                //Writting end of line
                strcat(string_file[0], "\n");
                printf ("%s\n", string_file[0]);

                //Write the file
                fputs(string_file[0],file_outputs);
                bucle=0;
            }   
        }
        //Closing the file      
        fclose(file_acquis);
        fclose(file_outputs);
    }

    mdl_terminate();
    /* insert other user defined application termination code here */
}
else {
    printf("Cannot locate the specified reference(s) in the shared library.\n");
    return(-1);
}   
return(CLOSELIB(handleLib));
```

}
}

Comment: Excel has nothing to do with strtok -- there is a clash between your expectations of what the text file that Excel creates looks like and what the text file that Excel actually produces looks like. Or -- perhaps the mismatch is between how the clipboard copies data and how you want it to copy data. In any event -- it is up to you as a programmer to figure out what delimiter to use with `strtok` in what context.

Answer (score 0):

As a default when Excel saves spreadsheet data as text it saves it in a tab-delimited format, but it sounds like Matlab saves it in space-delimited format. You can save an Excel spreadsheet as a CSV file but I'm not sure about space-delimited (although it would be easy enough to write a VBA macro to do so). One fix is to copy the data to Notepad, [replace tabs by spaces](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/how-do-i-delete-all-tabs-in-notepad/c804ae33-ab45-498e-8618-b5f9af89f74d?auth=1) and then to transfer to the result into the file that you are trying to read. The alternative is to write slightly more complex C code which can split on either spaces or tabs (note that you can pass `strtok` more than one delimiter).